# Altering existing message on TdxAlertWindowManager

Tags: delphi, devexpress, alerts

I use a piece of code like this to show an alert using the `TdxAlertWindowManager`.
This gives me one alert window and in this window there are several messages.
What I would like to do is to show an alert window with the first line of text and on the same window I would like to put a new text.
The program is used to connect a computer to some network shares and the message I would like to put looks like:

```
Connecting drive y: to \\server\foldery
Connecting drive x: to \\server\folderx
```

and so on for the rest of the shares.
But I can't figure out how to do it with `TdxAlertWindowManager`

Some years ago when I made the program I used `nxAlert` from Berg software, but I don't have it available any more. On that it was no problem to do this.

```
if fAlertWindow = nil then
  dxAlertWindowManager.Show(sHpAlertCaption, AlertText, fIndex).Tag := 1
else
  begin
    fAlertWindow.MessageList.Add(sHpAlertCaption, AlertText, fIndex);
    fAlertWindow.RestartDisplayTimer;
  end;
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the string like `'Connecting drive y: to \\server\foldery' + sLineBreak + 'Connecting drive x: to \\server\folderx'` ?

Comment: That doesn't quite do what I am trying to
I want the lines to be added as the connections are made to simulate some sort of progress indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make `TdxAlerWindowManager` to display new line but I know how to alter current messages. Just edit `Items[0]` property of the `MessageList`. I do it in timer.

```
var
fAlertWindow: TdxAlertWindow;

procedure TFMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fAlertWindow := dxAlertWindowManager1.Show('Caption', 'Hello1');
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TFMain.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fAlertWindow.BeginUpdate;
  fAlertWindow.MessageList.Items[0].Text := 'Hello2';
  fAlertWindow.EndUpdate;
  Timer2.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Works 100%